# insert character in specific position in a given string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to learn Regex and this question seems hard for me
I have a code like this

```
$string = "He is type a document"
```

the $string is input by user on a HTML form textarea, now I want to correct it to

```
$correct = "He is typing a document"
```

the code will scan through the sentence and make a stop at the word behind "he is" (or "she is","it is") then add "ing" to the last position of that word

Comment: You should provide us whatever regex you tried to do the work.

Comment: But the descripted algorithm would result in `He is typeing a document` if you simply add "ing" to the last position of that word. And what about `He is stupid` or `It is very nice to be here`. It would be `He is stupiding` and `It is verying nice to be here`.

Comment: yes i know, english is broad, all i am trying to do is correct the very basic one first (be + V_ing). I can substitute the "-ing" for the user easy to understan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<=(?:he is )|(?:she is )|(?:it is ))(\S*)\S
```

And replace with `$1ing`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cJ5pY2/9)

**Edit:** To restrict from matching words with `ing` use the following:

```
(?<=(?:he is )|(?:she is )|(?:it is ))(\S*)\S(?<!ing)\b
```

**Edit:** To make the replacement more meaningful use the follwoing:

```
(?<=(?:he is )|(?:she is )|(?:it is ))(\S+?)[aeiou]?(?<!ing)\b
```

This will give the following:

```
type -> typing
eat -> eating (not eaing)
break -> breaking (not breaing)
write -> writing
```

See [updated DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cJ5pY2/10)

Comment: thank you. It works for me, but what if the user input was right from the start, it will double "ing"

Comment: Thank you. Its perfect now :)

Comment: @user2986673 check the new update :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:s?he|it) is \S+\K
```

You can use this.Replace by `ing`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vA0yQ3/1

```
$re = "/^(?:s?he|it) is \\S+\\K/mi"; 
$str = "He is type a document\nshe is type a document\nit is type a document"; 
$subst = "ing"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But if users input the right sentence from the start, it will double the ing